# Is there a way to use a loop to tag mulitple items (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, loops, for-loop

This is the code I am trying to shorten. I would think there is a loop for it but I am not sure.

```
piker1.tag = 1
    piker2.tag = 2
    piker3.tag = 3
    piker4.tag = 4
    piker5.tag = 5
    piker6.tag = 6
    piker7.tag = 7
    piker8.tag = 8
    piker9.tag = 9
    piker10.tag = 10
    piker11.tag = 11
    piker12.tag = 12
    piker13.tag = 13
    piker14.tag = 14
```

Comment: There would be an easy loop if you had started with an array instead of giving your objects names-that-end-with-numbers. That was pretty silly. That is what an array _is_ — it's a way of associating successive numbers with objects.

Comment: You should learn about `IBCollection`.

Comment: And also consider whether using tags for views is relevant if you have references to the views already.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate variable names dynamically, since variable names need to be known at compile time, so you cannot do what you are trying to do.

If you put all buttons in an array, you can iterate through the array and assign the tags in a loop, but you still need to manually add the buttons to an array.

```
let pikers = [piker1, piker2,...piker14]
for i in 0..<pikers.count {
    pikers[i].tag = i
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `...pikers.count - 1` or `..<pikers.count`?

Comment: While this question will likely be closed, Andre, in Swift you can use range like ..<, but yes, either that or what you said... nm you just edited, heh

Comment: @AndréSlotta right, edited the answer, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way is to have an IBOutlet Collection instead of a simple IBOutlet for every picker.
[image]

Just drag and drop from the first picker as you would do with a simple outlet, but change the Connection to Outlet Collection. Then drag and drop the other pickers to the same outlet. You will get an array of pickers.
Then iterate over them:

```
for (index, picker) in pickers.enumerated() {
    picker.tag = index + 1
}
```

Voala!